# Simplifying column edit using stringr and pipes instead of gsub

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I am trying to remove the $ sign and , from a column and have so far been doing so by using gsub but am wondering if there is a way to do it using stringr inside pipes.

Example Code:

```
DataFrame <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18485, 18459, 18471, 18459, 
18459, 18459, 18499, 18513, 18513, 18513), class = "Date"), Payment = c("$10,000.00", 
"$2,000.00", "$500.00", "$500.00", "$5,000.00", "$4,000.00", 
"$5,000.00", "$500.00", "$20,000.00", "$3,290.00")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Current approach using gsub:

```
DataFrame$Payment <-gsub("\\$","",DataFrame$Payment)
DataFrame$Payment <-gsub("\\,","",DataFrame$Payment)
DataFrame$Payment <- as.numeric(DataFrame$Payment)
```

Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: Use `gsub('\\$|\\,', '', as.numeric(DataFrame$Payment))`.

Comment: Thanks, this simplifies it but I am interested in understanding what would be the tidyverse approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much anything can moved inside a `mutate`:

```
DataFrame %>% 
    mutate(Payment = as.numeric(gsub('\\$|\\,', '', Payment)))
```

If you want to use `stringr`, then try this:

```
DataFrame %>% 
    mutate(Payment = as.numeric(stringr::str_remove_all(Payment, '\\$|\\,')))
```

Comment: Excellent thanks for that! I was trying to get it into a pipe but kept on getting errors. This worked perfectly

Answer (score 5):

Well actually `gsub` with a character class is already pretty terse:

```r
DataFrame$Payment <- as.numeric(gsub("[$,]", "", DataFrame$Payment))
```

Comment: I agree, I think what I am curious to understand is how the character removal and the column type change would work inside a pipe using stringr